# Excel Date/Time Lookup Error

Tags: excel, vba, date, time, format

I have two columns of 15 minute date/time interval data. One is formatted in 24-hour time and the other 12-hour. These come from two different sources, and *reformatting the source data is not an option*. All of these intervals are showing as exact matches (even as values), but when I use a lookup formula (INDEX/MATCH & VLOOKUP) or even VBA, a match for every third interval is not being identified. I have attached sample pictures with formulas as well as my code below. Thanks in advance!

[image: Example]

[image: Example with formula view]

```
Sub MatchTest()
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 2 To 22
If CDate(Cells(i, 1).Value) = CDate(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
    Cells(i, 8) = Cells(i, 2)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select        
Else:   
    Cells(i, 8) = "NA"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select      
End If  
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `If Abs(Cells(i, 1).Value - Cells(i, 3).Value) < 0.0000001 Then`.  I suspect that one of the numbers has been rounded very slightly.  (Not unusual behaviour for non-integral values.)

Comment: I cannot re-create the issue without the source files, I bet they include milliseconds?  I suspect @YowE3K is correct.  Maybe this would be one of those times to use `.value2` instead of `.value` for the `CDate()` Function

Comment: @YowE3K and Joshua Fenner . You guys are both exactly right. I never considered milliseconds which makes sense since these are interval reads for power output. The "<0.000001" method worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Cdate, Timevalue and Datevalue can be used can be used. The TIMEVALUE function returns a serial number of a time. The DATEVALUE function converts a date that is stored as text to a serial number that Excel recognizes as a date.

For instance, Timevalue of 08/12/2008 20:00:00 and 08/12/2008 08:00PM yields the same result 0.833333333335759

Datevalue of same date in different format will also yield same result

```
TIMEVALUE(TEXT(yourdate, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS"))
TIMEVALUE(TEXT(yourdate, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM"))
DATEVALUE(TEXT(yourdate, "DD MMMM YYYY"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey all thanks for your answers. All three of these methods worked.

```
 If TimeValue(Cells(i, 1).Value) = TimeValue(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
 If DateValue(Cells(i, 1).Value) = DateValue(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
 If Abs(CDate(Cells(i, 1).Value) - CDate(Cells(i, 3).Value)) < 0.000001 Then
```

Comment: The last method should include the `Abs` function - i.e. `If Abs(CDate(Cells(i, 1).Value) - CDate(Cells(i, 3).Value)) < 0.000001 Then`